# To what movies do the soundtracks in this Masha and the Bear episode belong?

Tags: soundtrack, reference, masha-and-the-bear

In the episode [Den kino](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3965012/?ref_=ttep_ep10) Masha and the Bear decide to film a movie, but can't agree on what movie to film; they show a few scenes inspired by well-known movies, then as the pace picks up the episode only plays some movies' soundtracks.

Which movies are those?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a music ID question

Comment: @Paulie_D so far, I only found this Meta discussion: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/are-identify-this-song-questions-on-topic The highest ranked answer said "can be kept, if the identification contributes to the understanding of the film/scene in question". Is there any more recent decision about this?

Comment: @Paulie_D it's a "movie soundtrack" ID question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain about all movies, thus I will post this as a community wiki and hope the remaining gaps will be filled. I think, they did not play the exact soundtracks, but rather similar music that references the originals.

I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLrLv_e5EmY) to roughly note the times.

Here is my attempt:

- [2:25] ? - The music style is clearly like in a silent film, but I am not sure, whether it belongs to a specific film, or just the genre.
- [3:25] [Forrest Gump][2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)
- [3:45] [Zorro][3](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=zorro&s=tt&exact=true&ref_=fn_al_tt_ex) (the film or one of the series?)
- [3:55] [Titanic][4](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1) (the 1997 version)
- [4:22] [Snow White][5](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029583/?ref_=fn_al_ch_1a) (probably the Disney version from 1937)
- [4:45] [King Kong][6](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0024216/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) (probably the 1933 version)
- [5:05] [Avatar][7](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1)
- [5:30] [Star Wars][8](http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=star%20wars&s=tt) (yeah well, just pick one ;) )
- [5:40] [Mission Impossible][9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117060/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1)
- [5:45] ? some Russian film with regional background ?
- [6:08] Same music as Masha And The Bear's First Episode [11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSdGB_r6ZkQ), hence their telling their own story